# Python http.server won't work if i dont turn off Windows Firewall

Tags: python

I am using Python's newest http.server library, i tried this :

`py -m http.server --bind 192.168.1.123 1234 --dir desktop/server`

But this doesn't work for other devices, and turns out i have to turn off the windows firewall, and it works!

Anybody knows how to do this without turning off the Windows Firewall?

Comment: You can add the specific port as an exception to the firewall instead of turning it off completely. The point of the firewall is to control which ports can be reached on your machine, so it would make sense that it would block other devices if no exception is added for port 1234.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
py -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0 1234 --dir desktop/server
```

Then go to `192.168.1.123:1234` in your other device.

With `0.0.0.0` your are binding to your local network.

Comment: @BullittZulfiqar I am happy to hear that. Please mark it as solved. There is button with that option next to the answer.